# How to pass a object in popup to parent using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to get a object include value of id and value of name from popup to parent.

this is parent page.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function openPopup(){

    window.open("popup.do","aaa","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, width=420, height=500");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>


<form id=memberForm name=memberForm method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="popup" onclick="openPopup()" value="openPopup" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</form>
<!--  -->
</body>
</html>
```

this is a popup page

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function closePopup(){
    var valuePopupId=document.popupForm.popupId.value;
    var valuePopupName=document.popupForm.popupName.value;
    opener.document
    opener.memberForm=document.popupForm;
    //opener.memberForm.id.value=valuePopupId;
    //opener.memberForm.name.value= valuePopupName;
    window.self.close();
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>



<form id="popupId" name="popupForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="popupId"/>
    <input type="text" name="popupName"/>
    <input type="button" name="button" onclick="closePopup()" value="close"/>

</form>
<!--  -->
</body>
</html>
```

for explaining the codes, this codes pass each value of id and value of name from popup to parent. but I want to pass the values using a object.

what should I modify in the codes?

Comment: NB: popups are user-unfriendly and are often blocked by modern browsers unless you tick an option. Use overlays instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) API, but it's discouraged and many browsers will block it or the whole pop-up anyways.

Another way, if absolutely needed (I think things like paypal use this) is to pass the information through the server and back to the application using e.g. polling or a websocket.

The usual way, if you don't absolutely need the new window, is implementing the pop-up as a floating div, styled with CSS.